# how to add different styling in looped data (mapping)

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to add different styles in both mapped data. I use library antd for the dropdown, and I have default style for dropdown which is `radius: 8px` but for this dropdown, I need to style it a bit different, and I have mapped my dropdown

`index.js`

```
                <DropdownGroup
                    label="test"
                    dropdowns={[
                      {
                        options: [],
                        componentProps: {
                          className: "w-full",
                          onChange: (e) => {
                            alert("asd");
                          },
                        },
                      },
                      {
                        options: [],
                        componentProps: {
                          className: "w-full",
                          onChange: (e) => {
                            alert("asd2");
                          },
                        },
                      },
                    ]}
                  >
               </DropdownGroup>
```

`component.js`

```
        <div classname="dropdown-group">
         {dropdowns &&
           dropdowns.map((e, idx) => {
             return (
              <Dropdown
                key={idx}
                label={e.label}
                componentProps={e.componentProps}
                value={e.value}
                options={e.options}
              />
            );
          }
        </div>
```

`dropdown.less`

```
.dropdown-group{
    display: flex;
    .ant-select-selector:first-child{
        border-top-right-radius: 0px ;
    }
    
}
```

and the result like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvZFJ.png)

What I'm trying to do is, how do I style
`border-top-right-radius: 0px; border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;` 
just for the first dropdown

I have tried to use `:first-child` and it seems not right.

Any advice is appreciated, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

`dropdown.less`

```
.dropdown-group {
  display: flex;
  &:first-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 0px ;
  }
}
```

or just add

```
.dropdown-group:first-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
}
```

Either way is to add pseudo class `:first-child` in the parent element to effect the first child of it.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but because I use antd library, the class to change the border should be `.ant-select-selector` without this, the styling cant be done.

Comment: @hutp3a I see. Have you tried `:first-of-type`? Just change to `.ant-select-selector:first-of-type {}` and see if works. If you have to use `first-child`, you need to find the direct parent of `.ant-select-selector` (eg. `.ant-select` and set `.ant-select :first-child+.ant-select-selector {}` ). You can try either of these suggestions.